# how to fix the "router no longer defaults the history prop to hash history" warning?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

i'm using browser history and here is my code in routes.js

```
 export default (
   <Router history={browserHistory}>
     <Route path="/" component={Main}>
       <Route path="home/:username" component={Home}>
         <IndexRoute component={HomeContent}></IndexRoute>
         <Route path="widget/:second" component={Widget}></Route>
         <Route path="email/:second" component={Email}>
           <Route path="compose" component={ComposeEmail}></Route>
           <IndexRoute component={CheckEmail}></IndexRoute>
         </Route>
         <Route path="social/:second" component={Social}></Route>
         <Route path="calendar/:second" component={Calendar}></Route>
       </Route>
       <IndexRoute component={Login}></IndexRoute>
     </Route>
   </Router>
 );
```

and i used this.context.router.push('/') to make a navigation. and i have no idea why this warning is keep showing in my console?

```
 "Warning: [react-router] `Router` no longer defaults the history prop to hash history. Please use the `hashHistory` singleton instead."
```

i already read the documentation at https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#no-default-history but it does not really help.

i appreciated any help :)

Comment: Could you update this code snippet to include the `import` or `require` statement for `react-router`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `hashHistory` instead of `browserHistory`. Considering you're using the `import` synthax you can import `hashHistory` from `react-router` to replace `browserHistory`.

```
import { hashHistory, Router, ... } from 'react-router';

const history = new hashHistory();

export default (
  <Router history={history}>
  ...
  </Router>
);
```